# CloudFormation ECS ContainerDefinitions expected type: JSONArray, found: String

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a CloudFormation template and get the following error:

(It is a YAML file)

Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/ContainerDefinitions: expected type: JSONArray, found: String)" (RequestToken: d23861e3-70c3-2777-96ce-18b46a118437, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

I had to remove some values from the code below, but apart from that its the same layout.

```
ECSTaskDefinition:
Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
Properties:
  ContainerDefinitions: !Sub |
    [
      {
        "name": "web",
        "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:latest",
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "containerPort": 80,
            "hostPort": 80,
            "protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "value": ""
          }
        ],
        "ulimits": [
          {
            "name": "nofile",
            "softLimit": 65536,
            "hardLimit": 65536
          }
        ],
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "secretOptions": null,
          "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "/ecs/web",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The pipe in your container definition will enforce a string in yaml. This is the line with the issue.

`ContainerDefinitions: !Sub |`

follow the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

Comment: Thanks, I did it in YAML in the end. Its a shame there was no way to embed it in as JSON.